# When calling DLL Imported function. Next line of code is never reached?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, interop, extern

I am calling an imported C++ dll (a custom OpenGL window dll) function from C# using this:

```
[DllImport("Renderer.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadModelsAndMotions", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void LoadModelsAndMotions(string[] modelFiles, int nModels, string[] motionFiles, int nMotions);
```

I have about four or five functions which I use. The only problem is this function when called results in the next line of code in my c# app never to be reached.

If I run it inline with my code, my UI locks up until it is complete but the code after is not executed.

If I run it in an async task the code after this call in the task is never reached.

If anyone has any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Look in the Output window for "First chance" exception notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking whether the signature of the imported method is right (if it's really `string[]` parameter, look at [MarshalAsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). You can also try adding `SetLastError = true` to the attribute, if that changes anything.